# Is it posible to join relation without primary key attribute?

Tags: schema, relational-algebra

I have go through this but I couldn't understand. Can I join reation without primary key or partial key? If yes what is the answer for following question.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can join on any columns in a query. Primary and Foreign Keys are for Referential Integrity.

```
Select Item.IName, Item_Supply.AvailableQuantity
From Item
Join Item_Supply ON Item.ItemKey = Item_Supply.ItemKey
JOIN Supplier ON Item_Supply.SupplierKey = Supplier.SupplierKey
JOIN Country ON Supplier.NationKey = Country.CountryKey
JOIN Region ON Country.RegionKey = Region.RegionKey
Where Item_Supply.AvailableQuantity > 1000
AND Region.RName = 'East Asia'
```

Comment: Not sure what DBMS you are using, but I coded MSSQL

Comment: I need relational algebra not a sql query

Comment: So you should be able to convert my select statement into your relational algebra. If you can post your answer after, I'd like to see the result.